# Can't see written file on iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I want to save as csv my database table. But I can't find the file on iPhone after saving the file. Path is

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Is iOS has path like android's

```
Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
```

Comment: This path is the sandbox's `Documents` folder's path. Have you successfully written files to this folder? You can use `Directory.GetFiles();` to list them.

Comment: it is write and read correctly by application from this directory but I want to export csv from my application and I want to save it to use next time. I export csv but I could not keep it where the users could read

Comment: I am new at ios and I think it is impossible after ios 8. But I am not sure so I send csv with mail now :)